# How to identify if glue crawler is triggered manually or through a step function or through any other service of aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I have a step function which calls a lambda which triggers a glue crawler. The problem is sometimes this glue crawler is triggered unknowingly so is there a way through which we can identify whether the crawler is triggered manually or through so other some other service of aws ?